# In Pgfplots, how can I prevent points from hiding lines

Tags: pgfplots

When I plot two curves on the same graph with Pgfplots, I would like the second to be placed above the first. However, if the first has lines+points and the second only lines, then the point from the first go above the lines of the second.
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot[red,mark=*,line width=2pt] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
        \addplot[blue,line width=2pt] coordinates {(0.5,0) (1.5,2) (2,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

As you see, the blue lines goes above the red one, but the red point is above the blue line. I would like all that is in red to be placed below the blue.

I think I can do what I want with two `axis` environments overlaying, each one with one curve. But is there a solution in the same `axis` environment?

Comment: OK, thanks to the question cited as duplicate, I managed to pass the points below the blue line. But why is there such a difference of layers for points and lines?

Comment: If I use `on layer=background` on the red curve, nothing changes; if I use `on layer=foreground` on the blue, it's good. So it seems like the points are not sensitive to the `on layer` option?

Comment: Okay, I found the real question duplicate with my own is not the one cited in the header, but this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121579/pgfplots-markers-and-lines-on-different-layers